# How to convert currency is there any way or any plugin available?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I am working on E-commerce website and I am using craft commerce for that.Is there any way or any plugin available for that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Craft cms provide a plugin to convert currency.
Here is the link:
https://github.com/leowebguy/craft-currency-converter

You can use this plugin as we have already used it and it's very easy to implement with Craft Commerce. You can convert the currency value using one line code in a twig template using this plugin. This plugin is using rapidapi for live currency rates.

I hope this will help.

Thanks.